# Link stays blue in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

My site is at [kenastonchiropractic.com](http://kenastonchiropractic.com/index.php)

In Chrome, the "Home" link stays the color of the other links and they all turn white upon hover. In Firefox, however, the "Home" link is blue and stays blue even after it is clicked on (but it does turn white on hover). IE appears to behave rightly, as in Chrome.

I have tried many things and had no results. Maybe somebody can see my error.

Thank you!

Comment: For future reference, it is normally required to include the relevant problematic code with your post in addition to a link to an external website.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 not just "normally". I have voted to put on hold.

Comment: You should also notice that you do not have a <span></span> tag in the home link. You have it at all the other places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid such problems, you're always better off setting colors directly on links similar to this:

```
a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

And, you should also keep your browser versions updated in case you haven't.

Comment: Ah... this solved my issue. Thanks! Why I ignored this part of my code I do not know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```css
#nav ul li:hover a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

The default browser pre-set overrided your CSS rule because it is more specific.

The other links aren't affected because you wrapped them with `<span style="color:#fff">`, which overrides their default colors.

PS: On Chrome it shows a blue color just like all other browsers.

Comment: obligatory css specificity link w/ Star Wars references :) - http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: This addition did nothing at all, unfortunately. If I wrap the link in question with the span, then it does not turn white on hover at all. It is permanently whatever color is in the span.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Home" link is the only one that's not wrapped by `<span style="color:#fff">`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `padding` to the `a tags` not the `li`.

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pD7V4/1/)**.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Patient Process</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Health Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    color:#583709;
    transition:.5s all;
}

ul li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
}
```